# Jsp 404 exception

Tags: java, spring, jsp, http-status-code-404

I know this question was asked many times, but i looked through all answers i found, tried to do many things, but didnt success. Tell me if my searches just was not enough)

So, i'm dealing with java, spring and jsp server pages. In my webapp folder i has index.jsp and i just want to have possibility to jump from this index page to another jsp, located in webapp/WEB-INF/pages/. I wrote in mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml (located in WEB-INF) this code:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
   <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
   <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

index.jsp looks like this:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tables</title>
</head>
<body>
...
<br/>

<a href="adminMain" target="_blank">Admin main page</a>
<br/>
<a href="userMain" target="_blank">User main page</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Running the program, i'm expecting that when i press link "Admin main page", i'll jump to webapp/WEB-INF/pages/adminMain.jsp, but instead i have 404 error (page not found). Tell me where the things went wrong, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to map your .jsp to an endpoint that you can browse to through a Spring @Controller:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

 @GetMapping("/adminMain")
 public String adminPage() {
     return "adminMain";
 }

}
```

Have a look at the Spring MVC documentation on this: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-controller

Comment: O, thanks for the answer! Im new at Spring MVC as you guessed. And I hoped naively that will be able to test jsp without controller ready. Okay, i'll continue writing controller and reading docs from the link. Thanks.